# Actualizar vista en oracle

Tags: oracle

Tengo una tabla por ejemplo `Personas` que tiene 20 datos, ahora creo una vista a partir de esa tabla y la llamo `Personas_V`, que tiene los 20 datos de la tabla `Personas`.

Si añado 2 datos a la tabla `Personas` tendría 22 datos en esta tabla pero en la vista sigo teniendo 20, ¿no se actualiza automáticamente?

El script que ejecute fue :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "PERSONAS_V" as SELECT MSID.Identification_PK AS Identification_PK FROM PERSONAS MSID;
```

Comment: Sí. Claro que se actualiza automáticamente. Lo más probable es que te falte hacer el commit de la operación de inserción y por eso no te aparecen cuando los consultas en la vista. Si el motivo es este tampoco te aparecerán haciendo una select sobre la tabla Personas

Comment: Si es una vista materializada no se actualizaran hasta el periodo de actualización que hayas puesto.

Comment: si he hecho el commit pero sigue la vista con los mismos datos, como puedo hacer que se actualice automaticamente?

Comment: Como te comenta @Lithorell, salvo que hayas creado una vista materializada te debería devolver los datos actualizados. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta para añadir el script que utilizas para crear la vista?

Comment: acabo de actualizar la pregunta con el script

Comment: ¿Y ese script te funciona? ¿Con qué versión de Oracle estás trabajando?

Comment: perdon, he actualizado el script

Comment: ¿Y creando la vista así te da diferente resultado `SELECT Identification_PK FROM PERSONAS_V` que si haces `SELECT Identificacion_PK FROM PERSONAS`?

Comment: es verdad, si es asi de simple funciona, yo lo he reducido porque tiene tb join y creo que es un problema los joins

Answer (score 3):

En tu caso estás modificando los datos de la tabla original, lo que debería verse reflejado en la vista. Si no estás viendo los cambios reflejados prueba a ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
ALTER VIEW NombreVista
COMPILE;
```

Te dejo enlace a la [documentación oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4004.htm)

Ya que en Oracle no tenemos como en SQLserver la siguiente opción:

```
EXEC sp_RefreshView NombreVista
```

Podría estar ocurriendo que los metadatos de la vista no se actualizan automáticamente cuando modificas las tablas, pero en Oracle esto no tendría mucho sentido.

Si la vista fuera materializada, una posible solución sería:

```
SQL> CREATE materialized view log on emp
  2  WITH rowid, primary key, sequence (deptno, job)
  3  INCLUDING new values
  4  /

Materialized view log created.

SQL> CREATE materialized view emp_mv
  2  REFRESH fast on commit
  3  as
  4  SELECT deptno, job from emp
  5  GROUP by deptno, job
  6  /

Materialized view created.
```

Para dejarlo como anotación, las vistas tienen dos propósitos fundamentales:

1. Las vistas pueden ocultar la complejidad

Si tiene una consulta que requiere unir varias tablas, o tiene una lógica o cálculos complejos, puede codificar toda esa lógica en una vista y, a continuación, seleccionarla de la vista como si fuera una tabla.

2. Las vistas pueden utilizarse como un mecanismo de seguridad

Una vista puede seleccionar ciertas columnas y / o filas de una tabla y los permisos establecidos en la vista en lugar de las tablas subyacentes. Esto permite que aparezcan sólo los datos que un usuario necesita ver.

PD. Estás utilizando "OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW" por algún motivo o porque has visto y lo ejecutas sin más? Se emplea para procedimientos almacenados. La cláusula "force" le dice a Oracle que reemplace la vista de que ya existe. En principio, sin saber más de tu caso, diría que no es necesario.

Te dejo un código de ejemplo porque con la información que suministras no podría hacerlo con tus datos. Si la amplías, podría ayudarte.

Para crear una vista en Oracle es suficiente con:

```
create view vd1 
as select * 
    from dept2
     where loc like ‘D%’;
```

Y esta se actualizará automáticamente cada vez que accedamos a la vista. Si insertamos nuevos datos en la vista, se verán en ambas tablas:

```
INSERT INTO vd1 (deptno, dname, loc) 
VALUES (70,'MARKETING','DENVER');
```

Ahora bien, si insertamos un dato que no cumple la condición de que comience por D, no nos dará error pero no se mostrará en la vista; sí en la tabla. Por ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO vd1 (deptno, dname, loc) 
VALUES (80,'LOGISTICS','MIAMI');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo esto se arreglaría con la clausula *check option*, en ese caso, de introducir Miami, los cambios no se reflejarían ni en la tabla ni en la vista.

```
CREATE VIEW vd2
AS SELECT * 
    FROM dept2
    WHERE LOC like ‘D%’
    WITH CHECK OPTION;
```